# Change MapBox Basemap to Natural Earth II?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Apologies if this is basic, I've tried to find an answer...

Apparently to add a basemap, I need to change the "style", like here:

> style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/***satellite-v9***',

But how do I add this mapbox basemap (Natural Earth II)?
https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2.html

... and how to I change basemaps outside of the few that are shown here?
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/setstyle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to create your own source because Mapbox does not have a public style with this tileset.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({ 
  container: 'map', 
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9', 
  hash: true, 
  center: [-93.6135, 42.0256], 
  zoom: 15, 
  pitchWithRotate: false
});

map.on('load', () =>{
    map.addLayer({
      id: 'naturalearth',
      source: {
        type: 'raster',
        tiles: ['https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.natural-earth-2/{z}/{x}/{y}.png']
      },
      type: 'raster'
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks - now, how do I add that to my js file?


Here's what I have now:

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      hash: true,
      center: [-93.6135, 42.0256],
      zoom: 15,
      pitchWithRotate: false,
    })

Comment: ugh... don't know how to make comments clear, here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bq86n6k4/

Comment: I updated the original answer and jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tr2sqdqd/